# How to embed a report from Power BI?

Tags: angular, powerbi

How to embed a report from Power BI Report Server into an Angular application? Found only one article that says it's impossible, but the article was written a long time ago - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Can-you-embed-reports-from-Power-BI-Report-Server/td-p/197779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `<iframe>` tag, set its source to be the URL of the report and add [`?rs:Embed=true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/developer-handbook-overview#embedding) to it.

For example:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://myserver/reports/powerbi/Sales?rs:embed=true" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Only through the iframe? or can somehow differently.

Comment: Different in what way? Everything "different" eventually will boil down to an iframe in your page.